# Is it possible to sign in with user_email in Wordpress?

Tags: login, forms, users

is it possible to sign in with **user_email** instead of **user_login**, please ?

Thanks.

Comment: You could build a plugin that replaces the username with the user email when they register.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how we do it:

```
$user = get_user_by('email', $email);
if (wp_check_password($password, $user->user_pass, $user->ID)) {
    // Login successfull, redirect if needed
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
}
```

Assuming of course that you got the $email and the $password variables from a POST request or something :)

Answer (score 4):

Search and you will find... [WP Email Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-email-login/)